# Ubuntu 13.04 -- Installation loop

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.04

My laptop (Dell Inspiron 7520) came pre-installed with Ubuntu 12.10 (it even has a Ubuntu sticker on it) but I wiped it out and switched to Windows 8.

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 with a LiveUSB. After selecting "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 8" option, the laptop restarts and goes back to the same screen (Install Ubuntu or Try Ubuntu). It seems to be stuck in a loop.

Comment: If you have an USB, why not to install it in the HDD in it's own partition, instead using WUBI?

Comment: I thought that WUBI was scraped for Ubuntu 13 and onwards. Is it possible to install it via WUBI?

Comment: Did you installed Win8 on a GPT and UEFI or on a MBR with BIOS? If the first, then it may be the problem. Try the second :)

Comment: Pardon me, I have no idea what you just said. How do I determine how my Windows 8 copy is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You say it came with 12.10. If it's still possible to re-install Ubuntu 12.10, you may want to do so.

I know I had problems trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu on my fathers computer as it is quite old, but managed to install an older version of Ubuntu and then update it by using the `do-release-upgrade` in the terminal.